# Can someone help me understand this stack trace?

Tags: asp.net, stack-trace

I am getting an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error from a page on my site emailed through to me. When I go to that page, I don't get any errors though. Could someone explain what "could" be happening based on this stack trace. I know something is wrong with the render but I don't know where to go from here ... Thanks.

```
at ASP.controls_si_item_ascx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: That's a pretty deep trace; sure you don't have some accidental recursion happening?

Comment: This control has a parent control it is derived from but I don't think it is looping through incorrectly as I have removed the initialse from the parent control. This generally works fine, its just a random error :/

Comment: Is this MVC? And is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289269/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object) any use?

Comment: No it's not MVC and I don't think the post is helpful. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to see the cause of the problem after setting Debug="True" in my Web.config file.

Finally found the answer to this :) In my .ascx file, I have some JavaScript that selected a tab based on a controls ID. It turns out in some situations that control isn't available and therfore raises an object ref error. This WAS my code:

```
var hdnSCSSelectedTabIndex=$('#<%= hdnSCSSelectedTabIndex.ClientID %>');
var tabIndex = hdnSCSSelectedTabIndex.val();
```

and I am now doing this:

```
<% if (hdnSCSSelectedTabIndex != null) { %>
    var hdnSCSSelectedTabIndex=$('#<%= hdnSCSSelectedTabIndex.ClientID %>');
    var tabIndex = hdnSCSSelectedTabIndex.val();
<% } %>
```

Has sorted the problem out.

Hope this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 2):

If the exception happens in the codebehind you could try deplying a debug version to get the line number in the stacktrace.
Also I would look at the IIS request logs to get a clue of the request causing this.

Check out the [compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0.aspx) section of your web.config. You can enable debugging mode there and it should add the line numbers to the stack trace I suppose.

Comment: How would I go about getting a line number this occurs on? I didn't know this was possible in ASP.NET.

Comment: I'm not sure but it may work because there is code which gets generated and compiled for the control. Look for *controls_si_item_ascx* in the ASP.NET cache folder.